# Customize User Account Approved Email

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, email-template

I'm new to Joomla and I'm taking over some other person's previous work.

I'm trying to change the wording of the email that a new user receives after they've verified their email and the administrator has activated their account. I know that I have to do the customization in the language file but I can't find the correct constant.

I've tried overriding `COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATED_BY_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY` and 
`COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATE_SUCCESS` but I still get the same results. I also opened up `en-GB.com_users.ini` and I did a search for the wording that is on the default email and I can't even find it. So I don't know where it's getting the wording from. I've successfully overridden the User verification email constant, so I don't know why I'm having such a difficult time with this one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Those constants are located in `/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini`

My guess is that you are looking for `COM_USERS_EMAIL_ACTIVATED_BY_ADMIN_ACTIVATION_BODY` constant in administrator language folder and you should look for it inside **site language folder**.

Comment: Yeah, thanx. If you read my entire questions you'll see that I tried this already. It's just this one that I'm having a difficult time with. I did a search for the text that is being rendered and it doesn't appear in either. I still  changed it in the admin language folder and the site language folder but I still get the same result.  I also tried overriding it in Extensions->Languages->Overrides with no results. 
I know it has to be this constant because I've looked at the `activate()` method in com_users's registration model. My guess is that it's being overridden somewhere else. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I finally found the solution.

The email is being generated by a system plugin. That's why I couldn't override it like the other constants. So I had to change the text generated in the plugin's template file.

[Admin Approval](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/admin-approval/) is used and from what I read it's suppose to add email verification. I thought Joomla already came with this functionality by default, so there was no need for an add-on extension. But since this site was created a few years back, I'm guessing maybe this functionality wasn't available then so there was the need for this plugin.